# could anyone help me on Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Can anyone please help on Test class for below APTS_LineItemProcessing method especially for Salesforce API part i.e Creation of layer part. I have tried but code coverage is 20% only 1-70 lines covered after 71-end uncoveredlines I have tried but not to able to cover as I am new to salesforce.

Apex class:

```
global  class APTS_BrokerageLineitemProcessing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    public List<APTS_Message_center_temp__c> templist=new List<APTS_Message_center_temp__c>();
    public Id gCProgramId;
   
    global APTS_BrokerageLineitemProcessing(List<APTS_Message_center_temp__c> tempRecs,Id programId){
        TriggerContextUtility.runcode=false;
        for(APTS_Message_center_temp__c mcp : tempRecs){
            for(Id ids : mcp.APTS_LineItemIds__c.split(',')){
                APTS_Message_center_temp__c tc=mcp.clone(false,false,false,false);
                tc.APTS_LineItemIds__c=ids;
                templist.add(tc);
            }
        }
        GCProgramId=programId;
    }
    global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return templist;
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<APTS_Message_center_temp__c> scope){
        TriggerContextUtility.runcode=false;
        for(APTS_Message_center_temp__c mcp : scope ){
            for(Id ids : mcp.APTS_LineItemIds__c.split(',')){
                   APTS_LineItemProcessing(GCProgramId,ids,mcp.APTS_MarketId__c ,'Draft' , mcp.APTS_Action_Type__c );
            }
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            //This checkbox is to prevent duplicate invokation of Batches in the Brokerage Screen for LineItem creation for Draft Markets..
            APTS_Triggercontrol.runonce=false;
            APTS_Program__c Pg=new APTS_Program__c();
            Pg.Id=GCProgramId;
            Pg.APTS_ActivedraftJob__c=false;
            update Pg;
       
    }
```

{I need help on this below method , Unabe to cover this method }

```
public void  APTS_LineItemProcessing(Id programId,Id lineitemId,Id marketId,String actiontype,string proposaltype){
        TriggerContextUtility.runcode=false;
        string Action=Actiontype;
        Id PgId=ProgramId;
        Id MkId=MarketId;
        Boolean CreateLayers=false;
        
        
        Id CartId;
        map<Decimal,Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c> PrimaryLine=new map<Decimal,Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c>();
        map<Decimal,List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c>> ParentBundleNumber=new map<Decimal,List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c>>();
        Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c Layer=new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c();
        set<decimal> MasterPrimLineNo=new set<decimal>();
        set<decimal> ChildPrimLineNo=new set<decimal>();
        set<Id> mastPavId=new set<Id>();
        map<Id,Id> mastChdId=new map<Id,Id>();
        Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c liLay=[Select Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c FROM Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c WHERE Id =:LineitemId];
        //From Master Quote...
        for(  Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c li:[Select id,Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c,Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c,Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c from Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c where Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c =:LiLay.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c  and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Program__r.id =:ProgramId and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Proposal_Type__c='Master' order by Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c asc]){
            mastPavId.add(li.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c);
            MasterPrimLineNo.add(li.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c);
            If(li.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c==null){
                Layer=li; 
            }else{
                PrimaryLine.put(li.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c,li);
                if(ParentBundleNumber.containsKey(li.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c)){   
                    ParentBundleNumber.get(li.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c).add(li);
                }else{
                    ParentBundleNumber.put(li.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c,new list<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c>{li});
                }
            }
        }
        List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c> existingLst=[Select Id,Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c from Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c where APTS_Master_Line_Item__c=:Layer.Id and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Market_Child__c=:MarketId and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Proposal_Type__c=:proposaltype and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Program__c=:ProgramId];
        If(!existingLst.isempty()){
            Decimal lineNumber=ExistingLst[0].Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c;
            List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c> exstLineitems=[Select Id,Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c,APTS_Release_Status__c,Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c,APTS_Master_PAV__c from Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c where Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c=:LineNumber and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Market_Child__c=:MkId and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Proposal_Type__c=:proposaltype and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Program__c=:PgId];
            
            for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c Ali : exstLineitems){
                mastChdId.put(Ali.APTS_Master_PAV__c,Ali.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c);
                ChildPrimLineNo.add(Ali.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c);
            }
            if(ChildPrimLineNo.equals(MasterPrimLineNo)){
                CreateLayers=false; 
                for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c ext : exstLineitems){
                    ext.APTS_Release_Status__c=Action;
                }
                Update exstLineitems;
                set<string> apiFields=new set<string>();
                for(APTS_PreventAttributeUpdate__c pvst : [Select Id,APTS_apiname__c from APTS_PreventAttributeUpdate__c]){
                    apiFields.add(pvst.APTS_apiname__c);//These Fields need to be exempt while copying from the Master PAV..
                }
                //This code is for updating the child attributes PAV if already Present
                string querynames='';
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult mppp = Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
                for(string apiName : mppp.fields.getMap().keySet()){
                    querynames+=apiName+',';
                }
                querynames=querynames.removeEnd(',');
                List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c> mpAppold=database.query('Select '+querynames+' From Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c where Id IN  :mastPavId');
                List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c> pvLst=new List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c>();
                for(Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c pv : mpAppold){
                    if(mastChdId.containskey(pv.Id)){
                        Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c chd=new Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c();
                        chd.Id=mastChdId.get(pv.Id);
                        for(string api : querynames.split(',')){                    
                            if(!apiFields.contains(api) && pv.get(api)!=null){
                                chd.put(api,pv.get(api));
                            }
                        }
                        pvLst.add(chd);
                    }
                }
                update pvLst;
            }else{
                for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c ex : exstLineitems){
                    ex.APTS_Is_DeletePrevented__c = true;
                }
                update exstLineitems;
                Delete exstLineitems;
                CreateLayers=true;
            }
        }else{
            CreateLayers=true; 
        }
        CartId=[Select Id from Apttus_Config2__ProductConfiguration__c WHERE Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Market_Child__c =:MarketId and Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Program__c=:ProgramId and  Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.APTS_Proposal_Type__c=:proposaltype Limit 1].Id;
        If(CreateLayers){
            set<Id> Pid=new set<Id>();
            for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c pli :  PrimaryLine.values()){
                Pid.add(pli.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c);
            }
            Pid.add(Layer.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c);
            Map<String,Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c> pocMap=new Map<String,Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c>();
            for(Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c poc:[SELECT Id,Apttus_Config2__ComponentProductId__c,Apttus_Config2__ParentProductId__c 
                                                               FROM Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c where Apttus_Config2__ParentProductId__c IN : Pid]){
                                                                   pocMap.put(poc.Apttus_Config2__ParentProductId__c+'_'+poc.Apttus_Config2__ComponentProductId__c,poc);
                                                               }
            //Creation of Layer
            Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.AddBundleRequestDO request = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.AddBundleRequestDO();
            request.CartId = CartId;     
            request.SelectedBundle = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedBundleDO();        
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedProductDO();        
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.ProductId = Layer.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c;   
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.Quantity = 1;
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.StartDate = null;
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.EndDate =null;
            List<String> customFields = new List<String>();
            customFields.add('APTS_Master_PAV__c');
            customFields.add('APTS_Master_Line_Item__c');
            customFields.add('APTS_Release_Status__c');
            customFields.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c');
            customFields.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c');
            customFields.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c');
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.CustomFields = customFields;
            Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c customData = new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c();
            customData.APTS_Master_PAV__c = Layer.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
            customData.APTS_Master_Line_Item__c = Layer.Id;
            customData.APTS_Release_Status__c = Action;   
            customData.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c =Layer.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c;
            customData.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c = Layer.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c;
            customData.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c = Layer.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c;     
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedProduct.CustomData = customData;
            request.SelectedBundle.SelectedOptions = new List<Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO>();
            If(ParentBundleNumber.containskey(Layer.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c)){  
                for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c opt : ParentBundleNumber.get(Layer.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c)){
                    If(pocMap.containskey(Layer.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c+'_'+Opt.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c)){
                        Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c poc=pocMap.get(Layer.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c+'_'+Opt.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c);
                        Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO selectedOptionDO = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO();
                        selectedOptionDO.ComponentId =poc.Id;
                        selectedOptionDO.ComponentProductId =poc.Apttus_Config2__ComponentProductId__c;
                        selectedOptionDO.Quantity = 1;
                        selectedOptionDO.SellingTerm = null;
                        List<String> customFieldsOptions = new List<String>();
                        customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Master_PAV__c');
                        customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Master_Line_Item__c');
                        customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Release_Status__c');
                        customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c');
                        customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c');
                        customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c');
                        selectedOptionDO.CustomFields = customFieldsOptions;   
                        Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c liSOpt = new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c();
                        liSOpt.APTS_Master_PAV__c = Opt.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
                        liSOpt.APTS_Master_Line_Item__c = Opt.Id;
                        liSOpt.APTS_Release_Status__c = Action; 
                        liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c =Opt.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c;
                        liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c = Opt.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c;
                        liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c = Opt.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c;    
                        selectedOptionDO.CustomData = liSOpt;
                        request.SelectedBundle.SelectedOptions.add(selectedOptionDO);
                    }
                    if(ParentBundleNumber.containskey(opt.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c)){
                        for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c li : ParentBundleNumber.get(opt.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c)){
                            If(pocMap.containskey(Opt.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c+'_'+li.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c)){
                                Apttus_Config2__ProductOptionComponent__c poc=pocMap.get(Opt.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c+'_'+li.Apttus_Config2__OptionId__c);
                                Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO selectedOptionDO = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO();
                                selectedOptionDO.ComponentId =poc.Id;
                                selectedOptionDO.ComponentProductId =poc.Apttus_Config2__ComponentProductId__c;
                                selectedOptionDO.Quantity = 1;
                                selectedOptionDO.SellingTerm = null;
                                List<String> customFieldsOptions = new List<String>();
                                customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Master_PAV__c');
                                customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Master_Line_Item__c');
                                customFieldsOptions.add('APTS_Release_Status__c');
                                customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c');
                                customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c');
                                customFieldsOptions.add('Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c');
                                selectedOptionDO.CustomFields = customFieldsOptions;   
                                Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c liSOpt = new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c();
                                liSOpt.APTS_Master_PAV__c = li.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
                                liSOpt.APTS_Master_Line_Item__c = li.Id;
                                liSOpt.APTS_Release_Status__c = Action; 
                                liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c =li.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c;
                                liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c = li.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c;
                                liSOpt.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c = li.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c;    
                                selectedOptionDO.CustomData = liSOpt;
                                request.SelectedBundle.SelectedOptions.add(selectedOptionDO);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.AddBundleResponseDO response;
            Decimal linenumber;
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                response = Apttus_CPQApi.CPQWebService.addBundle(request);
                linenumber=response.LineNumber;
            }else{
                linenumber=3;
                Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c li =new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c();
                li.Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__c=CartId;
                li.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c=linenumber;
                li.Apttus_Config2__ItemSequence__c=1;
                li.APTS_Master_PAV__c=Layer.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
                Insert li;
            }
            List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c> liList=[Select id,Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c,APTS_Master_PAV__c,Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c,Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c from Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c where Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c=:linenumber and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__c=:CartId];
            List<Id> oldPavs=new List<Id>();
            for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c cli : liList){
                Cli.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c=Cli.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceNumber__c;
                Cli.Apttus_Config2__PrimaryLineNumber__c=Cli.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceLineNumber__c;
                Cli.Apttus_Config2__ParentBundleNumber__c=Cli.Apttus_Config2__CopySourceBundleNumber__c;
                oldPavs.add(Cli.APTS_Master_PAV__c);
            }
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                Update LiList;
            }
            Id recId=Layer.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
            DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = recId.getSObjectType().getDescribe(); 
            List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>( describeResult.fields.getMap().keySet() );  
            String query =    'SELECT ' +        String.join( fieldNames, ',' ) +    ' FROM ' +          describeResult.getName() +      ' WHERE ' +         ' Id IN :OldPavs ';  
            List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c> records = Database.query( query );
            map<Id,Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c> mpold=new map<Id,Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c>(records);
            List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c> attrlst=new List<Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c>();
            for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c cli : LiList){
                Apttus_Config2__ProductAttributeValue__c pv=mpold.get(Cli.APTS_Master_PAV__c).clone(false,false,false,false);
                pv.Id=Cli.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c;
                pv.Apttus_Config2__LineItemId__c=cli.Id;
                Attrlst.add(pv);
            }
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                Update Attrlst;
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: @rahulgawale Thanks for your response. I already referred the link which you sent but it is not helping my case since my Apex class is difficult.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing). Also if you have a very specific problem related to this, please edit your question, focus on that. If you are requesting here to cover up your whole class, apparently, your question will be closed. Also, use the `{ }` button to add syntax-highlight to the code.

Comment: @rahulgawale make sense. I really need a help on APTS_LineItemProcessing method like API parts

Comment: How to cover Salesforce API Part?  
i) Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.AddBundleRequestDO request = new Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.AddBundleRequestDO();
ii) Apttus_CPQApi.CPQ.SelectedOptionDO